# Let $X=\left\{ f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R \;\big|\; \lVert f\rVert_X<\infty,\ f(0)=0\right\}$. Show $(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert_X)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, holder-spaces

The following is a problem on an old Analysis preliminary exam at my institution; I'm prepping for the prelim. The problem is:

Let $$X=\left\{ f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R \;\big|\; \lVert f\rVert_X<\infty,\ f(0)=0\right\}, \quad \lVert\cdot\rVert_X =\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{1/2}}.$$ Show $\left(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert_X\right)$ is complete.

For earlier parts of this problem, I have already shown that $X\subseteq \mathcal C[0,1]$, and that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_X$ is indeed a norm on $X$. We have that $\left(\mathcal C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty\right)$ is complete, which should be helpful, though I can't see how exactly to use it here.

Comment: well, a closed subset of a complete metric space is also complete. Maybe this would help?

Comment: @Tomas You mean that you think I should first show that $(\mathcal C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_X)$ is complete? And then show that $(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert_X)$ is closed? It's not clear to me why that would be easier than directly attempting to show that $(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert_X)$ is complete.

Comment: @Tomas In fact $X$ is _not_ a closed subset of $C([0,1])$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich True. Did not check it.

Comment: @Ceph As DavidC.Ullrich observed, X is not a closed subset of $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint regarding the usefulness of the completeness of $C[0,1]$:

Say $f_n$ is Cauchy in $X$. You can show that in general $||f||_\infty\le ||f||_X$, hence $f_n$ is also Cauchy in $C[0,1]$. So you have $f$ with $||f_n-f||_\infty\to0$. That does not show by itself that $||f_n-f||_X\to0$, but it does give you a handle on things - at  least now you *have* the limit, you just have to show the sequence actually converges to $f$ in $X$.

Comment: I see. And so for any $x\neq y$, $\epsilon>0$, we have that for sufficiently high $n$: $|f_n-f(x)-f_n(y)+f(y)|<\frac\epsilon{|x-y|^{1/2}}$, by triangle lemma and then by the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ in supremum norm. This in turn gives us convergence in $X$ norm.

Comment: @Ceph It's not clear to me whether the argument you have in mind is correct, since you don't give many details. But it sounds wrong. Sounds like "sufficiently large" depends on $x$ and $y$; you need to show that if $n$ is sufficiently large then that inequality holds for all $x\ne y$. To put it another way: It sounds like you're deducing $||f_n-f||_X\to0$ from $||f_n-f||_\infty\to0$, and that simply doesn't follow. I called my answer a _hint_ - for the last step, which I didn't do at all, you're going to need to use $||f_n-f_m||_X\to0$ again.